# Graphvis output is not shown in Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

Colab is not showing the output of a Graphviz plot (for example https://graphviz.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html). How can I achieve it simply in Colab? I even tried to plot it's generated PDF file but it's not straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call `g.view()`. Just end the code with `g` is enough, like this:

```
g = Digraph('G')
g.edge('Hello', 'World')
g
```

Here's a minimal example [notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1PVtFECaDgMfVjed4XNtvyeL4pyMvPdAT)